# Spring LDAP search by "ObjectGUID"

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap, uuid

I am trying to query my ldapTemplate with "objectGUID" as -

```
String myGuid = "\\00\\B2\\15\\6C\\7D\\1B\\4B\\C8\\BF\\87\\C5\\36\\86\\A8\\B0\\16";
List<Object> attributes =  ldapTemplate.search("", new EqualsFilter("objectGUID", myGuid).encode(), new MyGUIDMapper());
```

I do have a my base environment setting mapped as -

```
<beans:entry key="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary" value="objectGUID objectSid"/>
```

This is able to fetch `objectGUID` as `byte[]`. But while querying the ldapTemplate I am not getting any result back.

Is this correct implementation of querying by `objectGUID`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `EqualsFilter` (or any other subclass of the `CompareFilter`) only expects plain-text fields and encodes them to avoid LDAP code injection.

To avoid this encoding, you can use a `HardcodedFilter` instead. If needed, you could validate the value before searching to avoid any injections, if you didn't actually encode the plain-text GUID yourself.

This also works if you want to use the `objectSID` field.

```
ldapTemplate.search("", new HardcodedFilter("(objectGUID=" + myGuid + ")").encode(), new MyGUIDMapper());
```